# SQL Trigger - Update field where date is older than current date

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I've got a table of events, with a date on which they occur in the db. So naturally, when an event has finished, it needs to not be displayed on the website. Currently I have a flag in the table for 'active'.

I'm wondering what the best way to handle the events that have passed. I thought the best way to be to create an event in phpmyadmin so that at 1am, all events that have gone past their date, will have their 'active' flags set to 0, but I heard that this is not the best way to do it, as it has more overhead and unnecessary i/o.

Another option would be to handle it in the db query. Select * from events where date > date AND active = 1.

Both work, but having an 'active' flagged event, that is not actually active sort of frustrates me.

What is the best way to handle this, and if a trigger/event in phpmyadmin is the way. How do I go about that?

Comment: Why bother with the active flag?  Why not solely filter on date?

Comment: I use the active flag for something else, but could also use it for the trigger. My question was, which would be better and why. Filter by date or using a trigger to update the active flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a view for this:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, ( date > now() ) as IsActive;
    from table;
```

If you really want to have the burden of creating a trigger and maintaining the field, then you can do that.  However, it doesn't seem worth it when a view handles this quite easily.